# Mid Point (Locus) Rectangular Hyperbola

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

If a rectangular hyperbola have the equation, $xy = c^2$, prove that the locus of the middle points of the chords of constant length  2d   is  $(x^2 + y^2)(x y - c^2) = {d^2} xy$.

I tried to apply the same  logic of mid point of the contact of contact(h,k) which is applied on circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ as $hx+ky=h^2+k^2$ but not getting any success.

Comment: @amd This question is pending for long time, if possible can you help me with this question

Comment: @amd After trying i got the answer